# Django app with fcgi works only in non daemonized mode

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am sorry if this is an obvious problem, but I really at my wits end trying to figure this out.

I have a Django application which I am running as an fcgi process and with Lighttpd as the front server.

I first tried running the Django FCGI process as suggested in the documentation (shown below)

```
python ./manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=9030
```

However, when I try to access the application from my web browser, I get a **'Page unavailable'** message.

Then I tried running the fcgi process in non daemonized mode (hoping to see some error messages on the screen), and this time I was able to access the application from my browser, and **everything worked fine**.

```
python ./manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=9030 daemonize=false
```

I experience this strange behavior on the server, whereas on my local development machine, everything works fine even when the fcgi process is daemonized.

I have also tried using 'prefork' instead of 'threaded' method, but that too does not help.

I am posting relevant portions of my Lighttpd config file, though I doubt anything is wrong with it...

```
$HTTP["host"] == "ideas.mydomain.com" {
    debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
    fastcgi.debug = 1
    fastcgi.server = (
        "/ideas.fcgi" => (
            "main" => (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 9030,
                "check-local" => "disable",
            )
        ),
    )

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/.*)$" => "/ideas.fcgi$1",
    )
}
```

The error log from Lighttpd has these 2 lines which show that it is indeed trying to connect to the fcgi process.

```
2012-02-28 08:48:49: (mod_fastcgi.c.3071) got proc: pid: 0 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:9030 load: 1 
2012-02-28 08:48:49: (mod_fastcgi.c.1492) released proc: pid: 0 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:9030 load: 0
```

Does anyone have a clue about what might be going wrong ? I do not see any fcgi related debug logs, even when I have debug=true in the command line options for starting fcgi. Do I need to do anything special to see debug logs from the fcgi process ?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post django fastcgi logs ? (tip: set runfcgi arguments **errlog** and **outlog**).

Comment: @jpic The errlog does not have anything significant, but I will configure the server to generate outlog as well, and post it here. Please give me a day or two... just in the middle of a deployment. Thanks.

Comment: If nothing is significant in any log, we'll have to strace your processes ... that's a lot harder because of the quantity of output we'll have to deal with.

Comment: @jpic I got it to work on another virtual server. I am thinking there is something about the Python/Django software stack or dependencies on the original, which is causing it to fail. Not sure which dependency is acting up, but I am not totally sure if it's worth the effort to find out ...

Comment: @jpic I guess I should do that. I was hoping someone has noticed a similar issue and might share their experience, but it's probably better to close it.

Comment: Sometimes my virtualenv is broken (probably linked to some OS lib that was deleted in favor of a newer version), i redo the virtualenv and everything is back to normal.

Comment: @jpic Is there a way to distribute the 50 credits between you and Secator for trying to help ?

Comment: No, but i didn't do anything so :D

Answer (score 1):

I would start with enabling debugs in the [config](https://calomel.org/lighttpd.html) of lighthttpd and also setting [`fastcgi.debug = 1`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs%3aModFastCGI#Options).

When you have all logging and debugging turned on, try to access the site to save the errors in logs. Then you need to examine the main the error log.

The default location is `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`.

Comment: I added debug support for fastcgi in Lighttpd. I have edited my question and pasted 2 lines from the log file which suggest that Lighttpd is indeed connecting with the fcgo process on the specified TCP port. BTW, is it correct to add the line for debug support within the body of $HTTP["host"] == "ideas.mydomain.com" {...} in the config file (as shown in the edited question)?